# How do I use variadic templates to forward both type and value template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, sfinae

Let's say we have 3 types (S1, S2, and S3):

```
//type 1 (good type)
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct S1{};

//type 2 (good type)
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, int T4>
struct S2{};

//type 3 (bad type)
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct S3{};

//any other type is also a "bad type"
```

We want to create a type trait to determine if the type is either S1 or S2.
For brevity, we use variadic templates, as the details of T# are not very important:

```
//a type trait to determine if a type is either "type 1" or "type 2"
//We expect ::value to be true if we can match either type.
//false otherwise.
//*ignore cv-qualifier related details
template <typename T>       struct test:std::false_type{};
template <typename... Args> struct test<S1<Args...>>:std::true_type{};
template <typename... Args> struct test<S2<Args...>>:std::true_type{};
```

If we were to test this type trait, we can see that it does not work for S2:

```
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << test<S1<int,int,int>>::value << '\n';
  std::cout << test<S2<int,int,int,5>>::value << '\n';
  std::cout << test<S3<int,int,int>>::value << '\n';
```

**prints:**

```
true
false
false
```

It does not work for S2, because one of the template types are already defined (in this case T4 is already an int).

**Is it possible to use variadic templates to match all of the template types this way?**
Regardless of whether they are type names or actual types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template <class A0,class A1, class A2, int x> struct test<S2<A0,A1,A2,x>>:std::true_type{};
```

In general, meta meta programming with non-type template parameters is a pain.

Consider using stuff like `integral_constant` and the like if you are doing a lot of it: pass values as types instead of as values.  You can even pass templates as types.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that gives the output you want, without having to redesign your S2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct S1{};

//type 2 (good type)
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, int T4>
struct S2{};

//type 3 (bad type)
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct S3{};

template <typename T>       struct test : std::false_type{};
template <typename... Args> struct test<S1<Args...>> : std::true_type{};

template <template <typename, typename, typename, int> class P, typename A, typename B, typename C, int N>
struct test<P<A,B,C,N>> : std::conditional<
    std::is_same<P<A,B,C,N>, S2<A,B,C,N>>::value,
    std::true_type,
    std::false_type
>::type {};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, int T4> struct S2Wannabe {};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << test<S1<int,int,int>>::value << '\n';  // true
    std::cout << test<S2<int,int,int,5>>::value << '\n';  // true
    std::cout << test<S3<int,int,int>>::value << '\n';  // false
    std::cout << test<S2Wannabe<int,int,int,5>>::value << '\n';  // false
}
```

But redesigning S2 may solve your problems more easily.